# Convolution integral with non-trivial extremes of integration in python

Tags: python, convolution

for a given array `f` of size `N` that represents discrete values of a function of `x` I would like to evaluate

g(y) = integral from zero to y of f(x)*f(x-y) dx

in python.

How do I do that? I'm failing to see a solution, while the convolution would be easy, I fail to see a way to do this

thank you!

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve1d.html

Comment: thank you, would you mind providing an example on how to use it for my specific case? Thank you!